# NSArray clears after 3 times view did load

Tags: iphone, xcode, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have an NSArray that contains a couple of items. The NSArray is loaded into a uitableview from another class. when I back out of the detail view and re-enter (for the 3rd time), the NSArray is empty and the tableview is empty as well. What is happening? (I am using arc so I don't think it is a leak)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    myMatch = [[Match alloc] initWithId:1 OpponentId:13];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *askCellIdent = @"askCell";
    static NSString *answerCellIdent = @"answerCell";


    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {

        AskCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:askCellIdent];
        if (cell==nil) {
            cell = [[AskCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:askCellIdent];
        }

        cell.nameLabel.text = @"Albert asked:";
        cell.questionLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[myMatch.chat objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:1]];
        return cell;
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {

        AnswerCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:answerCellIdent];
        if (cell==nil) {
            cell = [[AnswerCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:answerCellIdent];
        }

        cell.nameLabel.text = @"Hugh answered:";
        cell.answerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[myMatch.chat objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:1]];
        return cell;
    }

}
```

Here is the init code of the my match class:

```
- (id) initWithId:(NSInteger)yourId OpponentId:(NSInteger)opId {
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil) {
        //set your id and opponents id to the match.
        [self setUserId:yourId];
        [self setUserId:opId];

        JSON = @"[{\"opponentId\":\"4\",\"chat\":[[\"1\",\"Does he have a beard?\"],[\"1\",\"No.\"]]}]";

        //initiate the chat array.
        chat = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init ];
        [self loadMatch];


    }
    return self;
}
```

and here is the chat property/synthesize

```
NSMutableArray *chat;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *chat;

@synthesize chat;
```

No idea whats going on, because the slog of the array is empty too!

Comment: When do you add values to `chat`?

Comment: try replacing this line :chat = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; with: self.chat = [NSMutableArray array];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare an int varable repeatCount in appDelegate

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ypurAppDelegate *appDelegate = (yourAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]   elegate];


          appDelegate.repeatCount++;

       if(appDelegate.repeatCount %3==0)
       {
           [array removeAllObjects];
            [tableview reloaddata];
        }
}
```

Comment: I follow the code, but how would this help and why does this solve the problem/why is it happening?

Comment: appDelegate.repeatCount++; increments value for every time your view loads, if(appDelegate.repeatCount %3==0) when the 3rd time loads  [array removeAllObjects]; empty the array

Answer (score 0):

Use self.chat = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init ]autorelease];   to initialize your array

Answer (score 0):

Instead ViewDidLoad, allocate the object in initWithCoder.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if( self )
    {
       myMatch = [[Match alloc] initWithId:1 OpponentId:13];
    }
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem with the populating the `NSMutableArray` as only once will `viewDidLoad` will be called. You should insert values into array in `viewWillAppear` Method or initiate the match class in `initWithCoder`.